# Convergence/ divergence of $\sum_{k\geqslant 1}\frac{1}{k+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi k}}(4(1-r)r)^k$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the series
$$
\sum_{k\geqslant 1}\frac{1}{k+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi k}}(4(1-r)r)^k.
$$
Why does it converge if $r\neq \frac{1}{2}$, why diverge if not?

---

If $r\neq\frac{1}{2}$, then $4(1-r)r<1$, but why does it converge then and why not converge if $4(1-r)r\geqslant 1$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

We have

- if $|a|<1$ then 
  $$k^2\frac{1}{k+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi k}} a^k\xrightarrow{k\to\infty}0\implies \frac{1}{k+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi k}} a^k=\left(\frac1{k^2}\right) $$
  so the series 
  $$\sum \frac{1}{k+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi k}} a^k$$
  is convergent by comparison with $\sum\frac1{k^2}$.
- if $ |a|>1$  then 
  $$\frac{1}{k+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi k}} a^k \xrightarrow{k\to\infty}\infty$$
  so the series is clearly divergent.
- if $|a|=1$ and since
  $$ \frac{1}{k+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi k}}\sim_\infty \pi^{-1/2}\frac1{k^{3/2}}$$
  then the series is absolutely convergent by comparison with $\sum\frac1{k^{3/2}}$

Now for what values of $r$ we have
$$4|r(1-r)|\le 1$$

Answer (score 0):

If  $|4(1-r)r|<1$, then  series converges by [ratio test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test).:

$$\lim_{k \to \infty}\frac{|a_{k+1}|}{|a_{k}|}=\lim_{k \to \infty}|4(1-r)r|\frac{(k+1)\sqrt{\pi k}}{(k+2)\sqrt{\pi (k+1)}}=|4(1-r)r|<1$$

If $|4(1-r)r|>1$ then series doesn't converges also by ratio test.

If $|4(1-r)r|=1$, then you have two cases:

First: $4(1-r)r=-1$, then series converges by [alternating series test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).

Second: $4(1-r)r=1$ (it's only when $r=\frac{1}{2}$), then series converges by integral test:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k+1)\sqrt{\pi k}} \leq \pi^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k\sqrt{ k}} < \infty$$

Because:

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}} dx < \infty$$